# How to use a function to read all files in directory and bind rows

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I want to use a function to read 12 files in a directory and bind the rows of all files together into one dataframe.
This is what I have so far (I am using `xl.read.file` to open the files because they're password protected):

```
processFile <- function(f) {
  df <- xl.read.file(files, password = "IIV628")
  df <- df[, c(2,15)]
  }

result <- sapply(files, processFile)
```

Using this, `result` becomes a list of 24. However, I want this to become one dataframe with the two columns I selected in the function

Comment: Use `dplyr::bind_rows(result)`, `data.table::rbindlist(result)`, or `do.call(rbind.data.frame, result)`.

Comment: See the dupe links for several other ways to work around this, namely something as direct here as `combined <- lapply(files, processFile) |> do.call(rbind, args=_)` (on R-4.1 or newer). If this doesn't work and the links don't provide more info, please @-ping me and we'll work through the differences. Hope it helps. Good luck!